# How can I generate two Weibull Random Vectors with a given correlation coefficient in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, random, probability, weibull, probability-distribution

I need to create two vectors X and Y containing both N samples. They are both weibull distributed with the same λ,k parameters and they are correlated with a correlation coefficient ρ that is neither -1 nor 1 nor 0, but a generic value that indicates a partial correlation.

How can I create them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the marginal distributions (a Weibull distribution), and you want to sample from the bivariate distribution in which the two components are correlated.  This can be done with a [copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)).

Here's an Octave script that is based on the bivariate Plackett copula.  (The script uses the [`logit`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) function, which in Octave is included in the `statistics` package. I don't have Matlab; I hope you can handle the Octave-isms in the script.)

The plots shown after the script show the results of the calculation.

Matlab has an [assortment of functions related to copulas](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/copula-distributions-and-correlated-samples.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav), which might allow you to simplify this code, or provide other interesting methods for generating the samples.

```
1;

% Copyright 2021 Warren Weckesser
% License (per stackoverflow terms): CC BY-SA 4.0
% (See https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)

function rho = spearman_rho_log(logtheta)
    % Compute the Spearman coefficient rho from the log of the
    % theta parameter of the bivariate Plackett copula.
    %
    % The formula for rho is from slide 66 of
    % http://www.columbia.edu/~rf2283/Conference/1Fundamentals%20(1)Seagers.pdf:
    %   rho = (theta + 1)/(theta - 1) - 2*theta/(theta - 1)**2 * log(theta)
    % If R = log(theta), this can be rewritten as
    %   coth(R/2) - R/(cosh(R) - 1)
    %
    % Note, however, that the formula for the Spearman correlation rho in
    % the article "A compendium of copulas" at
    %   https://rivista-statistica.unibo.it/article/view/7202/7681
    % does not include the term log(theta).  (See Section 2.1 on the page
    % labeled 283, which is the 5th page of the PDF document.)

    rho = coth(logtheta/2) - logtheta/(cosh(logtheta) - 1);
endfunction;


function logtheta = est_logtheta(rho)
    % This function gives a pretty good estimate of log(theta) for
    % the given Spearman coefficient rho.  That is, it approximates
    % the inverse of spearman_rho_log(logtheta).

    logtheta = logit((rho + 1)/2)/0.69;
endfunction;


function theta = bivariate_plackett_theta(spearman_rho)
    % Compute the inverse of the function spearman_rho_log,
    %
    % Note that theta is returned, not log(theta).

    logtheta = fzero(@(t) spearman_rho_log(t) - spearman_rho, ...
                     est_logtheta(spearman_rho), optimset('TolX', 1e-10));
    theta = exp(logtheta);
endfunction


function [u, v] = bivariate_plackett_sample(theta, m)
    % Generate m samples from the bivariate Plackett copula.
    % theta is the parameter of the Plackett copula.
    %
    % The return arrays u and v each hold m samples from the standard
    % uniform distribution.  The samples are not independent.  The
    % expected Spearman correlation of the samples can be computed with
    % the function spearman_rho_log(log(theta)).
    %
    % The calculations are based on the information in Chapter 6 of the text
    % *Copulas and their Applications in Water Resources Engineering*
    % (Cambridge University Press).

    u = unifrnd(0, 1, [1, m]);
    w2 = unifrnd(0, 1, [1, m]);
    S = w2.*(1 - w2);
    d = sqrt(theta.*(theta + 4.*S.*u.*(1 - u).*(1 - theta).^2));
    c = 2*S.*(u.*theta.^2 + 1 - u) + theta.*(1 - 2*S);
    b = theta + S.*(theta - 1).^2;
    v = (c - (1 - 2*w2).*d)./(2*b);
endfunction

% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
% Main calculation
% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

% rho is the desired Spearman correlation.
rho = -0.75;
% m is the number of samples to generate.
m = 2000;

% theta is the Plackett copula parameter.
theta = bivariate_plackett_theta(rho);

% Generate the correlated uniform samples.
[u, v] = bivariate_plackett_sample(theta, m);

% At this point, u and v hold samples from the uniform distribution.
% u and v are not independent; the Spearman rank correlation of u and v
% should be approximately rho.
% Now use wblinv to convert u and v to samples from the Weibull distribution
% by using the inverse transform method (i.e. pass the uniform samples
% through the Weibull quantile function wblinv).
% This changes the Pearson correlation, but not the Spearman correlation.

% Weibull parameters
k = 1.6;
scale = 6.5;
wbl1 = wblinv(u, scale, k);
wbl2 = wblinv(v, scale, k);

% wbl1 and wbl2 are the correlated Weibull samples.

printf("Spearman correlation: %f\n", spearman(wbl1, wbl2))
printf("Pearson correlation:  %f\n", corr(wbl1, wbl2))

% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
% Plots
% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

% Scatter plot:

figure(1)
plot(wbl1, wbl2, '.')
axis('equal')
grid on


% Marginal histograms:

figure(2)

wbl = [wbl1; wbl2];
maxw = 1.02*max(max(wbl));
nbins = 40;

for p = 1:2
    subplot(2, 1, p)
    w = wbl(p, :);
    [nn, centers] = hist(w, nbins);
    delta = centers(2) - centers(1);
    hist(w, nbins, "facecolor", [1.0 1.0 0.7]);
    hold on
    plot(centers, delta*wblpdf(centers, scale, k)*m, 'k.')
    grid on
    xlim([0, maxw])
    if p == 1
        title("Marginal histograms")
    endif
endfor
```

Terminal output:

```
Spearman correlation: -0.746778
Pearson correlation:  -0.654956
```

Scatter plot:

[image: scatter plot]

Marginal histograms (Weibull distribution with scale 6.5 and shape parameter 1.6):

[image: marginal histograms]

Answer (score 1):

Let me throw some simple idea. You have two identical distributions, same μ and same σ which could be derived from your Weibull λ,k parameters.

ρ = E[(X-μ)(Y-μ)]/σ<sup>2</sup>

and in general it is a measure of linearity between X and Y.

So lets split N samples into M and (N-M). For first M samples you use THE SAME sampled vector of Weibull(λ,k) for both X and Y. Last (N-M) samples are taken independently from Weibull(λ,k). So 2D picture will look like this - perfect linear dependency for first M points and then cloud of independent points.

The bigger is M, more correlated sampled are, and ρ is close to 1. Vice versa is also true - ρ is close to 1, then you have to make M large. The only question is to figure out M(ρ) dependency (have no idea at the moment, but will think about it).

Above we covered case of non-negative ρ. If ρ is negative it is the same approach only with antilinear dependency.

M(ρ) dependency should be monotonic one, and probably linear function as well, something like

M = int(ρ*N)

but I have no proof at the moment

Simple code sample (UNTESTED!)

```
a=3;
b=4;

N=1000;
M=100;

c = wblrnd(a,b, M, 1);

xx = wblrnd(a,b, N-M, 1);
yy = wblrnd(a,b, N-M, 1);

X = cat(1, c, xx);
Y = cat(1, c, yy);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it sounds great. Just a question: should I have to mix the elements of X and Y once I have generated them? Isn't it a too specific case if X and Y have exactly the same initial part of M samples?

Comment: @Kinka-Byo But you need part of both samples to be linearly denepdent, this is what rho is all about. I would propose simple test.  Write this as function which returns two correlated arrays, X and Y. Say, N=10000. Then st M to 500, and call this functions and compute rho between X and Y. Repeat this 1000 times and for a given M compute mean rho, E[rho]. Then set M to 1000 and repeat. M=1500 and repeat. And plot graph of E[rho] as y axis versus M/N (0.05, 0.1, 0.15, ...) as x axis. You'll quickly see if there is a linear dependency or not